# Zero in blank cells (pivot table)

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, zerofill

How can I show zero value in a blank cell inside a pivot table from the Google Sheets?

I know tha in MS Excel this is possible by right click on pivot table > Pivot table options but I don't know how to do it in google sheets

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet excluding any private or confidential data, but including your pivot table. And indicate where you wish to display zero values. ,